# How to render a bound Django model form as HTML-safe?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

[image: Textarea has plain text instead of HTML]I am trying to return a bound form that has been modified and has some arbitrary text and HTML inserted into it. I have done some research and have been able to successfully insert some arbitrary text into a bound form but I haven't found any way to render the injected HTML as HTML. It renders as plain text. How can I achieve my goal?

Here is the code:

```
# views.py

def multi_text(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.POST.copy()
        form = MultilineForm(data=data)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            form.data['text'] = '<i>Hello hello</i>'
            return render(request, 'multi_text.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        form = MultilineForm()
    return render(request, 'multi_text.html', {'form': form})

# forms.py

class MultilineForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['text'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'}, verbose_name='Text', placeholder='Type your text here...')
        self.data['text'] = '...'
    class Meta:
        model = Multiline
        fields = ['text']
        widgets = {
            'text': Textarea(attrs={}),
        }

# template.html

<form method="post" action="" class="form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.text.as_widget }}
        <span class="input-group-btn">
        <input type="submit" value="Check" class="form-control btn btn-primary">
        </span>         
    </form>
```

Comment: take a look at mark_safe (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe)

Comment: It's hard to know what you are asking, but I think you are perhaps looking for a WYSIWYG editor like TinyMCE?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I am trying to make a grammar checker like Grammarly. It has a text area where you can paste your text and then click the check button. The text will be returned with errors marked in red. I will add a screenshot to the post to make it clearer.